# Email SendTo addresses using custom Label is showing invalid email error

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

Following code showing error :

```
EXCEPTION_THROWN [105]|System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid:


    List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
    sendTo.addAll((System.Label.GratisOrderServiceEmail).split(';')); //for list of recepeint
   // system.debug(sendTo);
    mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have any of (a) a leading semi-colon, (b) a trailing semi-colon, or (c) multiple semi-colons in succession. For example, `;apple@example.com;;banana@example.com;` would have a total of 3 empty strings, which are not valid emails.

You can fix your code by checking for empty values.

```
Set<String> emails = new Set<String>(System.Label.GratisOrderServiceEmail.split(';'));
// Ignore blank values
emails.remove('');
sendTo.addAll(emails);
```